# Alamofire - Get the body response

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm getting crazy trying to find a way to get the server response exactly as the server is returning it from inside the `ResponseJSON` closure.

```
 sessionManager!.request(urlPath, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: encoding, headers: nil).responseJSON 
       (dateRequest) in
            //How can I obtain the server reply, not encoded from here?
             .
             .
             .
```

Comment: You might need to clarify what you're expecting to get, what you're actually getting, and possibly what the difference it.

Answer (score 2):

requestJSON passes a `DataResponse<Any>` instance to the closure, which looks like this:

```
public struct DataResponse<Value> {
    /// The URL request sent to the server.
    public let request: URLRequest?

    /// The server's response to the URL request.
    public let response: HTTPURLResponse?

    /// The data returned by the server.
    public let data: Data?

    /// The result of response serialization.
    public let result: Result<Value>

    /// The timeline of the complete lifecycle of the request.
    public let timeline: Timeline

    /// Returns the associated value of the result if it is a success, `nil` otherwise.
    public var value: Value? { return result.value }

    /// Returns the associated error value if the result if it is a failure, `nil` otherwise.
    public var error: Error? { return result.error }

    // ...
}
```

You'll find the response headers in `response.allHeaderFields` and the raw content body in `data`.